# Change color "BRANDS"

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://test2.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

I want to change the text color "Nike" to white.

If you change this text and change the name of the product and do not want this.

```
  a {
  color: #F7F6F6;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

Here's an image to better understand what my needs are.

http://i62.tinypic.com/2b41uw.png

Comment: Find the specific element that holds that text and style it accordingly.

Comment: will this CSS give you what you're looking for?

.wb-posted_in>a{color: white; } 

?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this piece of code.

```
.wb-posted_in a {
    color: white;
}
```

Tell me if works